# How to upload a high quality video to YouTube

Tags: youtube

How can I upload a high quality video to YouTube?

I have a 1080p video in format of MP4 and I want to upload it to YouTube with its original resolution, so I don't want YouTube to reduce its resolution to 360p. How can I do it?

Do I have to convert the MP4 to something else and then upload?

**Edit:**
When I upload the video, YouTube doesn't store its original size, and doesn't give an option to choose resolution; it really resizes the video and make it 360p. (So the user cannot choose other than 360p).
Is my video upload settings may be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a video to YouTube, it converts your video to allow to the user to choose the resolution. The original resolution will still be available.
Example:
If you upload a 1080p video, the user will have 144p, 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p and 1080p to choose.

Comment: If you want to have only 1080p available to watch, i don't know how to do it, and it wouldn't be a good thing, because users with slow connections are going to stop watching the video in the beginning. Watching video with interruptions sucks

Comment: But my problem is this. When I upload the video, YouTube doesn't store its original size, and doesn't give an option to choose resolution; it really resizes the video and make it 360p :( (So the user cannot choose other than 360p).

Comment: Is my video upload settings may be the reason for this?

Comment: Try to convert the video using Handbrake, optimising it to web. Thats strange, because i upload 720p mp4 vids to youtube and they work perfectly on youtube

Comment: Are you sure the 1080p is unavailable? Maybe it's just not picking that playback resolution because, e.g. you didn't select it in the player or your bandwidth is too low.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry101 : I think 1080p or even larger is available (I have been seen 2000+p with the name 'Original'...) But you cannot select other than 360p for the videos I upload. My bandwith is 4.73mbps for download and 0.67mps for upload. Yes, this is low for 1080p. So may it possible that Youtube make my videos 360p, because of my moderate download/upload speed, while upload ?

Comment: @Bengi I'd guess that 4.73mbps is enough, but you can test it by trying to play someone else's video at 1080p. Another experiment is to ask someone whose computer and connection can play 1080p to play your video in that mode. YouTube seems to default to a lower resolution each time.

Comment: @Bengi it doesn't matter your internet speed while the upload. I think that your problem is with your render settings, try getting another.

Comment: pardon what do you mean for render ? sorry for my english

Comment: Is the video edited or not? If yes, you rendered it... So do you tried to use handbrake to convert the video?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [advanced encoding settings guide](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en) in order for your video to be stored and displayed in the highest possible quality.